# JavaFx Drag and Drop Image from one image view to another

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, imageview

Edited answer and updated code:

I have a javafx application and I want to drag an image from one image view to another in the same window. But I can't figure out a way to have the second image view accept and display the image.

```
    Image image = new Image("file:src/drag_and_drop_6/Notes.png");
    ImageView iv = new ImageView();
    iv.setImage(image);

    Image image2 = new Image("file:src/drag_and_drop_6/orca.png");
    ImageView iv2 = new ImageView();
    iv2.setImage(image2);


    iv.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
        Dragboard db = iv.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putImage(iv.getImage());
        db.setContent(content);
        event.consume();
    });

    iv.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            if (event.getGestureSource() != iv &&
                    event.getDragboard().hasImage()) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                }
            event.consume();  

             }
    });

    iv.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {

            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();

           if (db.hasImage()) {
                iv2.setImage(db.getImage());
            }
             event.consume(); 

        }
    });
```

Comment: Where are you actually trying to change the image displayed in the second image view? Can you include that code?

Comment: @James_D, I am working on an application in which the user shall be able to rearrange the nodes in a flow pane at will and according to importance. I am making first experiences with drag-and-drop and trying to figure out how things work.

Comment: I actually would like to be able to move the nodes using their IDs...

Answer (score 2):

I found the slipups myself at [Can't manage to do drag and drop in a GridPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297620/cant-manage-to-do-drag-and-drop-in-a-gridpane).

```
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putImage(iv.getImage());
    // instead of
    // content.putString(iv.getId());
```

and

```
    if (db.hasImage()) {
         iv2.setImage(db.getImage());
    }
```

Full rectified code is above.